# Class 'HttpSocket' not found

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I'm getting the error "Class 'HttpSocket' not found" even though I included

```
App::uses('HttpSocket', 'Network/Http');
```

before the class.  I'm using it like

```
$HttpSocket = new HttpSocket();
$results = $HttpSocket->post(DebugConstants::REGISTRATION_SITE, $info);
```

with cakephp version 2.4.5.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: How are you using/loading your class, and what version of CakePHP are you using? Please edit the question with that information (tag the question with the one tag corresponding to the version of CakePHP you are using).

Comment: You aren't showing enough code. A stacktrace would also help. With an error like that, in the absence of any evidence to the contrary, it looks like you're doing the equivalent of `> php MyClass.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your line in the model really looks like this:

```
App::uses('HttpSocket', 'Network/Http');
```

and not like this:

```
App::uses(... other classes ... , 'HttpSocket', 'Network/Http');
```

I don't really know why :) but in my case it mysteriously started to work after I extracted the two classes into separate App::uses();